# How to backup documents to s3 in a particular collection older than specific dates in a mongodb collection where timeseries data are stored?

Tags: mongodb, aws

I have mongodb database. 
I have a collection in that stores time series data, time values are stored as ISODate.

Older than few days are not required on database, but required to be backed up in aws s3. So later point of time if any thing historical required, can be restored.

This back-up process can be put in cron job.

How should it be done?

Is there a way using pymongo?

How to retrieve/restore the same when ever required?

My sample data is

`{
    "_id": "5a7ac31e12add91290d13f44",
    "booleandata1": false,
    "continuearming": false,
    "TIME": "2018-02-07T09:13:01.000Z",
}`

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? What does the data look like? (Add some sample data to your question). What does your table definition look like? (Add the DDL to your question) What does the backup procedure do? If you [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/206000/edit) your question and add some details, we might be able to provide you with an answer. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can export data as json and gzip:it with query where you define "timestamp older than..:" and you can do this even you don't have timestamp field, because you _id's (ObjectId) first four bytes is actually timestamp.

This query returns records older than 240 seconds

```
var ts=(Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000)-240).toString(16)+'0000000000000000';
db.test.find({"_id":{$lt:ObjectId(ts)}});
```